# Question about the Samādhirāja-sūtra

Tags: mahayana, sutras, nagarjuna

I have a similar question about the Samādhirāja-sūtra.

Is the Samādhirāja-sūtra, a mahAyAnA sUtra or does it occur in the nikAyas or somewhere else? What is the historically accepted date of this sUtra? Does this sUtra precede nAgArjuna or is it a post-nAgArjuna sUtra?

Comment: What is the reason for the strange edits? I just followed itrans.

Comment: I struggled to read the questions. I assume this forum is in the English language.

Comment: But sUtra, nAgArjuna etc are not English names. So I used itrans. If you struggled to read the question, how were you able to edit it by removing itrans?

Comment: With great difficulty.

Comment: Then you should learn itrans and not unnecessarily edit questions. Looks like the people who answered here had no issues.

Comment: It's unconventional to use capitals letters in that way. The usual way is to add an accent like "*sūtra*", or use simple lower-case without an accent like "sutra".

Comment: @ChrisW It is itrans scheme - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS

Comment: So you've said -- `The need for a simple encoding scheme that used only keys available on an ordinary keyboard was felt in the early days of the RMIM newsgroup where lyrics and trivia about Indian popular movie songs was being discussed.` It's the first I've seen it, though -- I think that, what I described is the convention on this site and elsewhere, for example ['Mahayana' and 'Mahāyāna'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahayana) on Wikipedia -- I think the more-conventional version is easier to read and write (so if you want to use that, I think that's what almost everyone else does).

Comment: @ChrisW itrans is easier for me, since I use normal keyboard. Simpler than others. Unless I copy paste, I cannot use other schemes.

Comment: Almost everyone uses a normal keyboard. So people write unaccented text, like "sutra" and "mahayana".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Mahayana sutra. Info. about the Samadhiraja sutra from the wiki page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samadhiraja_Sutra). Full infos. and whole sutra is available [here](http://read.84000.co/data/toh127_84000-the-king-of-samadhis-sutra.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. Is it pre-nAgArjuna or post-nAgArjuna?

Comment: Wiki says dating to c. 2nd century CE. Wiki says Nāgārjuna (c. 150 – c. 250 CE).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously its not in the Nikayas, per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samadhiraja_Sutra).